# Azure Application Gateway Ingress Configuration - retain same URL post moving to root level

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, tomcat8, nginx-ingress, azure-application-gateway

My ingress configuration is set up like below and the expected URL to access the site is `company.com/product`. It is a Tomcat-based application which used to be extracted from product.war. Now that I have moved it to ROOT level, I am unable to retain the same URL. I would like to have both
`company.com` and `company.com/product` to show as `company.com/product` in the browser address bar. Currently, the application loads as `company.com/login/login.jsp` while the expectation is to load `company.com/product/login/login.jsp`. This login page redirection is handled by the application.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-hostname: company.com
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: https
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/cookie-based-affinity: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    #appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: product
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /product
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* "/" {
         rewrite / https://company.com/product permanent;
      }
  generation: 3
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: website-ingress
  namespace: product
spec:
  rules:
  - host: company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: product-service
            port:
              number: 443
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - company.com
    secretName: product-sslcert
```

I have tried multiple approaches like specifying `backend-path-prefix`, `rewrite-target`, `configuration-snippet`, `server-snippet` but nothing has worked so far.

I also resorted to moving the application from product.war to ROOT.war as my attempts to set up a redirect from `/` to `/product` did not succeed either. I was under the impression that moving the application to the root level would allow me more customizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different approach to solving this problem. Instead of using the ingress, I decided to retain the product.war in `webapps` and updated the ROOT folder to only have an `index.jsp` file with this content -

`<% response.sendRedirect("/product"); %>`

With this change, I am getting the expected results i.e., `company.com` now redirects to `company.com/product`